Calling synchronized method in Project Reactor
I have a Reactor chain that calls a synchronized method as shown below. Whenever an auth token expires, I need to send a request to server to get new token, and getting new token needs to be called only once as multiple request can be active at a time. Because of this, refreshToken() is synchronized. The thing is refreshToken is called from Netty NIO threads. Does this cause any issue? What is the Reactor way of calling a synchronized method?
I couldn't find any reference to this in official documentation.
Mono<Result> process(Request request) {
    Header header = getHeader(); //use authString
    reactorHttpClient.get().uri(request.uri()).header(header)
        .onErrorResume(InvalidAuthException.class, () -> {
            //get new token from server and retry
            refreshToken();
        })
}

synchronized void refreshToken() {
    //send request to server and get token and update the mutable state authString
    authString = response.getToken();
}


Maybe you could do something like How to trigger Mono execution after another Mono terminates and implement it using Semaphore/tryAcquire etc instead of using synchronized.

@dan1stmightbehappyagain my concern is it good to do locking in netty threads?

Have you read How Do I Wrap a Synchronous, Blocking Call? in the Reactor documentation?

@MarkRotteveel yes I know Mono.fromCallable. My question is about running a piece of code and updating shared state only once.I don't know how Mono.callable can be used here.

It is about the second statement, using the bounded elastic scheduler. That said, you should try and avoid the need for synchronized if possible, but then again, it has been awhile since I tried anything with Reactor, so I don't know its ins-and-outs.

Thanks. My problem is about 2 or more Publishers updating the state. There can be many Mono publishers and each can execute refreshToken which I want to prevent.

Yes I know about it being about locking in reactive executions hence I suggested doing the locking using tryAcquire without blocking. However, that does require reactivating "waiting" executions when unlocking.
